# MYSQL How to exclude weekday between 2 different dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count number of days in between that date. I have 2 different dates, date1 name vcr_date and date2 name bbp_date. For example, vcr_date = '2019-01-01' is Tuesday and bbp_date = '2019-01-07' is Monday and the day count between that is 6 day. If I want to exclude Friday & Saturday, the count will be 4 day. How to do that in MYSQL?

Sample Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `datatest` (
  `vcr_date` date default NULL,
  `bbp_date` date default NULL,
  `comp_name` varchar(50) default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='InnoDB free: 102400 kB; InnoDB free: 99328 kB; InnoDB free: ';
#----------------------------
# Records for table datatest
#----------------------------

insert  into datatest values 
('2019-01-06', '2019-01-02', 'J.O.E SUPPLIER SDN BHD'), 
('2019-01-05', '2019-01-03', 'AURAJUBLI SDN BHD'), 
('2019-01-14', '2019-01-04', 'NEW MT CENTURY SDN. BHD.'), 
('2019-01-25', '2019-01-05', 'KMT SUPPLY SDN BHD'), 
('2019-01-10', '2019-01-06', 'SASHWIN SDN. BHD.'), 
('2019-01-17', '2019-01-07', 'J.O.E SUPPLIER SDN BHD');
```

SQL for counting days :

```
SELECT *,datediff(vcr_date,bbp_date) as daycount
FROM datatest
```

Comment: Subtract 2 times the number of full weeks between the dates. Can the start or end dates be on a Friday or Saturday? If they can, you'll need some extra adjustments to handle those cases.

Comment: if friday and saturday always fixed

Comment: The start and end dates cant be on Friday or Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in sql server as below and hope can help you a bit.

```
declare @start_dt date,
        @end_dt date
set @start_dt = '20190101'
set @end_dt = '20190107'

;with cte
AS
(
select @start_dt AS dt
UNION ALL
SELECT dateadd(day,1,dt)
FROM cte
WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@end_dt),0) and datename(dw,dateadd(day,1,dt)) not in('Monday','Saturday')
)
select count(*)
from cte
```

Comment: Thanks for reponse, I'd try this but didnt understand the sql. Can you elaborate it based on sample I added above.